# Maximal-Orthogonal Convex Hull (or Maximal-Rectilinear Convex Hull)

Tags: geometry, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, orthogonal-groups

Edit : Consider giving a reason for down vote.

In my research, I have come across a [this paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Lw2jVjh_CXb3BodEZJR0s5Z2c/view) from the Computational Geometry field and I am not able to understand the concept of Maximal-Rectilinear Convex Hull (or mr-convex hull) is given on page 160, Def 2.4 of the linked paper. In the attached image I have tried to explain my problem. Please read the image in the numeric sequence of 1 to 4 to understand my question.

[image],

Appreciate any help in clearing my confusion.

Comment: What is the reason for down vote? I am new to both Maths and Maths-Overflow. Would appreciate reasons for down voting as well.

Comment: I haven't voted on your question but I find it very hard to figure out exactly what you are asking. I suspect I am not the only one. Some advice which may be useful to you as a new member can be found here http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question

Comment: I just checked. The paper link was broken. Apart from that, I don't see what is wrong with the question. 
>>The question is precise. 
>>I have quoted a definition from a journal paper and I have given the link to it as well.
>> I have tried to make a sketch explaining my dilemma instead of trying to keep it in words.

I don't know what else shall I do.

Comment: I think this is a better fit for math.stackexchange. (Mathematically, the definition is elementary, so this question isn't really suitable for this specific site, even though it is a good question.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber appreciate the direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a confusing concept, as acknowledged
in the paper you cite,
"On the definition and computation of rectilinear convex hulls"
([Elsevier link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020025584900252)).

---

[image: WikiImage]

          

<sup>(Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_convex_hull).)</sup>

---

It may help to look at this more modern paper:

> Alegría-Galicia, Carlos, Tzolkin Garduño, Areli Rosas-Navarrete, Carlos Seara, and Jorge Urrutia. "Rectilinear convex hull with minimum area." In *Computational Geometry*, pp. 226-235. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2012.
>   ([PDF download](http://www-ma2.upc.edu/seara/data/publications/articles/area_minima2.pdf).)

Excerpt from A-G et al.:

---

[image: OrthoHull]

---

Comment: A-G et al. paper says on its second page : " Throughout this paper, we will use the maximal ortho-convex , or mr-convex hull stated by Ottmann et al." But the paper goes on giving definition of Rectilinear Convex Hull as [R-Hull of Point Set P] = [R^{2} - Union(Quadrants Free of Point Set)].  Does it mean, the algorithm discussed in Ottmann et. al. and A-G et al. gives the mr-convex hull of a point set and not the r-convex hull of the point set? Because using the definition of A-G et al., for three non-collinear points, I can only get the mr-convex hull and not the r-convex hull of the points.

Comment: @Abhinav: I don't see your confusion. They (A-G et al.) define "The 'Rectilinear Convex Hull' of *P* with orientation θ [as] the set" etc. And the remainder of their paper seems clear.

Comment: Consider the two definitions.
(1) Defn 2.4 in Ottmann et. al. of **mr-convex hull**
(2) Defn of **Rectilinear Convex Hull with fixed orientation** given in A-G et al. which can be seen [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Lw2jVjh_CXU25hRFVUWVBoYWs/view?usp=sharing)

Hence, for my example of 3 non-collinear points, both the definitions shall give the mr-convex hull. Because the r-convex hull of three non-collinear points can only be the three points themselves. So my confusion is : Is A-G et al. talking about r-convex hull but actually their algo gives mr-convex hull. Am I right?

Comment: >"their algo gives *mr*-convex hull.": I think your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

After understanding the logic of creating mr-convex hull of a set of points, I tried making a sketch that explains the idea clearly (hopefully) for a point set of 3 non-collinear points. You can access the sketch [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Lw2jVjh_CXY2JndTh3U1BGajg/view?usp=sharing). I have used the definition of mr-convex hull shown [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Lw2jVjh_CXU25hRFVUWVBoYWs) taken from this [paper](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_Lw2jVjh_CXQUJXaDc1X0M5Qk0).

Also, I think the two important papers in this field, [paper-1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Lw2jVjh_CXb3BodEZJR0s5Z2c/view?usp=sharing) and [paper-2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Lw2jVjh_CXQUJXaDc1X0M5Qk0/view?usp=sharing) are confusing on one aspect. Both papers read that the algo they present are for obtaining the r-convex hull  and then cr-convex hull (from the obtained r-convex hull) of a set of points. Whereas, I think both the papers' algo compute the mr-convex hull first and then the cr-convex hull (from the mr-convex hull).